# What is the diference between "pg_global" and "pg_default" in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

What is the main difference between these two tablespaces?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-tablespaces.html):

> Two tablespaces are automatically created by initdb. The pg_global tablespace is used for shared system catalogs. The pg_default tablespace is the default tablespace of the template1 and template0 databases (and, therefore, will be the default tablespace for other databases as well, unless overridden by a TABLESPACE clause in CREATE DATABASE).

Comment: How are they different physically?

Answer (score 0):

pg_default :all the user related objects are stored in pg_default tablespace

pg_global : all the system related objetcs are stored in pg_global tablespace